# Cleaning up scraping results to return anchor text, but not HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the prices of hockey sticks from the given URL. Eventually I'd also like to grab the names + URLs, but I don't consider that necessary to solving this.

Here's what I've got:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.prohockeylife.com/collections/senior-hockey-sticks'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

stick_names = soup.find_all(class_='product-title')
stick_prices = soup.find_all(class_='regular-product')

print(stick_prices)
```

The above code successfully returns prices of the hockey sticks, but it looks like this:

```
[<p class="regular-product">
<span>$319.99</span>
</p>, <p class="regular-product">
<span>$339.99</span>
</p>, <p class="regular-product">
<span>$319.99</span>
```

I'd like to clean it up and have only the actual price returned.

I've tried a few things, including:

```
dirty_prices = soup.find_all(class_='regular-product')
clean_prices = dirty_prices.get('a')
print(clean_prices)
```

But to little success. Pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but I think the following is what you may be looking for:

Instead of `print(stick_prices)`, use:

```
for name,price in zip(stick_names,stick_prices):   
       print(name["href"],name.text,price.text)
```

The start of the output is:

```
    /collections/senior-hockey-sticks/products/ccm-ribcor-trigger-3d-sr-hockey-stick 

        CCM RIBCOR TRIGGER 3D SR HOCKEY STICK     

$319.99

/collections/senior-hockey-sticks/products/bauer-vapor-1x-lite-sr-hockey-stick 

        BAUER VAPOR 1X LITE SR HOCKEY STICK


$339.99
```

etc.

Comment: Ok, let me try and repeat back what this is doing. The zip function essentially merges both variables together into a list(? - maybe a "tuple"). Then, with the for loop, you're iterating through each item, printing the href contents (from stick_names), only the text from stick_names, and only the text from stick_prices. Close?

Comment: @Stn - Right on the nose (though zip doesn't actually merge the variables; just picks one element from each). Zip is actually very useful - see more here, for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You need the .text property which you can also extract during a list comprehension. Then list/zip for a list of tuples of names/prices at end

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.prohockeylife.com/collections/senior-hockey-sticks'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}   
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
stick_names = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all(class_='product-title')]
stick_prices = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all(class_='regular-product')]
print(list(zip(stick_names, stick_prices)))
```